# cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode - SVG and Animated

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to handle a `svg` component with `Animated`. but I got this error message:

> Cannot add a child that doesnt have a YogaNode to a parent without a
>   measure function! (Trying to add a `RNSVGCircle` to a `RCTView`).

this is my code:

```
import { PanResponder, View, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity,Animated } from 'react-native'
import Svg, { Path, Circle, G, Text, Image } from 'react-native-svg'
```

---

```
        <Animated.View
          style={{transform: [{translateX: translateX}],width:widthHeight, height: widthHeight}} {...this._panResponderTwo.panHandlers}>
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill="#ff0000"
                {...this._panResponderTwo.panHandlers}
              />
        </Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createAnimatedComponent` function:

```
const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);
const AnimatedG = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(G);

<AnimatedCircle
          r={widthHeight}
          cx={widthHeight}
          cy={widthHeight}
          fill="#ff0000"
          {...this._panResponderTwo.panHandlers}
          />
```